# jms translation bundle: The format "yml~" does not exist.

Tags: php, symfony, translation, locale, yaml

In symfony2, with JMSTranslationBundle, when running

```
php app/console translation:extract fr --config=app
```

I get the issue

```
  [JMS\TranslationBundle\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  The format "yml~" does not exist.
```

my config being

```
jms_translation:
    configs:
        app:
            dirs: [%kernel.root_dir%, %kernel.root_dir%/../src]
            output_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations
            ignored_domains: [routes]
            excluded_names: ["*TestCase.php", "*Test.php"]
            excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs]
#            extractors: [jms_i18n_routing]
```

Any idea as how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to remove all `*.yml~` files from your project.

Comment: Presumably you could also add "*~" to the excluded_names?